# 404 error after deploying to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Before deploying my ASP.net software to the production site (Windows server 2012 R2), I first test the software on a test server.  If that is  succesful, I deploy (copy) the exact same software to the production site.

On the production site, I got the following error when clicking on a link:

*Warning, an 404 error has been detected: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The file '/Account/Login.aspx' does not exist. 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal...*

Note that the path '/Account/Login.aspx' was a part of the previous version of the deployed software. The path no longer exists in the current version.

I have tried to make a "clean-ip" by deleting the content in:

*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root*

but that did not help.

1. How do I find the root cause for the 404 error?
2. How do I prevent old stuff from previous versions of the deployed software from making trouble in the latest deployed version?

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: Search for 'Login.aspx' in the web.config on your production server. It is probably in your authentication section if you are using forms authentication

Comment: Notice that all code on the test server and production server are identical. This includes config files (except from the connection strings that are different of course).  In current version I  have switched to ASP.net identity after using forms (membership) in previous versions of the SW

Comment: The default "LoginPath" for ASP.NET Identity framework is "/Account/Login". Have a look in your Startup.Auth.cs file in the App_Start directory of your web app. If it is still the default path, update it there and redeploy to your prod environment.

Comment: The 'Startup.Auth.cs' already contains the following line: ' LoginPath = new PathString("/IdentityAccount/Login.aspx"),'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help me by adding comments to my question.

I have found that adding the following lines to 'web.config' file removes the error. I dont know why but the main thing is that it now works:

```
<appSettings>
....
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
<add key="UserLockoutEnabledByDefault" value="true"/>
<add key="DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan" value="10"/>
<add key="MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout" value="3"/>
```